# Saving numpy array to file in a single line?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

On the code bellow I want to save an array to a file in a single line using "numpy.savetxt" but I'm really not sure if I can get this result.

```
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    array = np.array([[ 6, -2.86751284, -0.35808319,  1.79360812],
        [ 6., -1.59351284, -0.02808319, -0.47039188],
        [ 6., 0.51848716,  0.21791681,  0.17060812],
        [ 6., 1.63251284, -0.12208319,  0.90460812],
        [ 6., -0.26051284,  0.03991681,  1.33660812],
        [ 6., 1.87948716,  0.43391681,  0.21960812],
        [ 6., 2.52048716,  0.45191681,  1.44760812],
        [ 6., 0.40448716,  0.04591681,  2.58360812],
        [ 6., 1.81248716,  0.30391681,  2.62260812]], np.float32)

    np.savetxt("img/file.txt", array, fmt="%.3d")
```

I wanted a result like "006, -002, -003, 001, 006, -001..." with all columns and lines in a single line in the file but separated by commas.
Can I do it with "numpy.savetxt" or do I have to loop through array to get this result?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you get in the file if you try running it?

Comment: Did You try it? What happened? please take the time to read [ask].

Comment: When I ran this code I get a file with 9 lines and 3 columns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should produce, what you want:

```
np.savetxt("file.txt", array.flatten(), fmt="%.3d", newline = ", ")

cat file.txt
006, -002, 000, 001, 006, -001, 000, 000, 006, 000, 000, 000, 006, 001, 
000, 000, 006, 000, 000, 001, 006, 001, 000, 000, 006, 002, 000, 001, 
006, 000, 000, 002, 006, 001, 000, 002,
```